Activity period of helion source
I have tried to find a lot of information about sporadic meteorshowers. Only about the Antihelion source there is a lot of literature. The Antihelion source e.g. has an activity period from 10 Dec - 20 Sep. Does anyone know more about the activity period of the Helion source? Is there a longer period without activity like the Antihelion Source?

Its a good idea to mention the sources for the info that you've found already,
